# int.Parse method without parentheses

Tags: c#, parsing, methods

Why can I invoke Parse method **without parentheses** since that method has 4 overloads?

For example in this case:

```
string[] aTemp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(aTemp, int.Parse);
```

Comment: You can't. The sample you posted does not *invoke* method. Can you please edit post to provide better more relevant example?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're right, but dana gave me the right answer so now I know why this isn't actually invoking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature for [`ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) is actually this:

```
public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(
    TInput[] array,
    Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter
)
```

Which the compiler can infer to be:

```
public static int[] ConvertAll<string, int>(
    string[] array,
    Converter<string, int> converter
)
```

From the signature for [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static int Parse(
    string s
)
```

If you wanted to write out in long hand:

```
Converter<string, int> converter = new Converter<string, int>(Int32.Parse);
string[] aTemp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] a = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(aTemp, converter);
```

Note: [`Converter<TInput, TOutput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y(v=vs.110).aspx) is actually a delegate that takes as input a parameter of type `TInput` and returns a value of type `TOutput`.

Comment: Ok @dana I got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Array.ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes two parameters, an array of TInput, and a [converter delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from TInput to TOutput.  There's only [one overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of int.Parse that matches the signature of a converter delegate -

```
public static int Parse(
    string s
)
```

Putting together all of the information available, we can pick the right method to call.